# What is an idiomatic way to handle failure in Racket?

Tags: racket

I am used to OCaml where I rely heavily on the `result` type, along with a monadic interface to handle failures in my applications. Exceptions do exist in OCaml but I rarely use them, except for working around the absence of a `return` keyword.

Is there such a trend in Racket (especially typed Racket)? What is an idiomatic way to handle and propagate failure in Racket applications?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few idioms:

### exceptions

Exceptions are used mainly for errors, but occasionally for other kinds of "exceptional" situations.

- `(vector-ref "hello" 0)` raises an exception, because a string is not a vector
- `(string-ref "hello" 72)` raises an exception, because the index is out of bounds
- `(open-output-file "/does/not/exist")` raises an exception if the path doesn't exist, or can't be opened because of permissions

### result values

Some functions return a union where the type acts like a datatype variant. A result of `X or false` is especially common.

- `(assoc 'a '((a . 1) (b . 2)))` returns the pair `(a . 1)`, but
- `(assoc 'c '((a . 1) (b . 2)))` returns false
- `(read-string 10)` returns either a string or the special `eof` object if there are no characters available before the end of the port

The `cond =>` syntax can be useful for dealing with `X or false` results:

```
(cond [(assoc key alist) => cdr] [else default-value])
```

### failure continuations

Some functions take an extra (usually optional) argument that determines what happens on certain kinds of failures.

- `(hash-ref ht key)` raises an error if `ht` doesn't contain an entry for `key`, but
- `(hash-ref ht key failure)` either calls `failure` (if it is a procedure) or just returns it (otherwise) if `ht` doesn't contain `key`
- but `(hash-ref not-a-hash-table key failure)` raises a contract violation exception; it doesn't call `failure`